# How To Plot A Curve of An Array and Array List?

Tags: java

I am creating a consumer and producer curve, each it's own class. The consumer has an array of points and the producer has an array list of points. I need to create a method the creates the "graph" (consumerCurve and producerCurve). In these methods it needs to check for invalid parameter (i.e. no negative numbers), instantiate the array/array list, and then instantiate the points/store them in the correct slots. Here is what I have for the consumerCurve:

```
public class ConsumerCurve {

private Point[] myConsumerCurve;

public void Curve()
{
    myConsumerCurve = new Point[10];

    for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        myConsumerCurve[x] = new Point(x,x);
    }
}

public ConsumerCurve(int np, double m, double b, int dx)
{
    //*1)check for invalid parameters
     Point[] myConsumerCurve = new Point [np];

     if ( np < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'np' must not be negative");
        }

    //2) Instantiate array using size n 
    for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    {
        int x = i*dx;
        double y = m*x+b;
        myConsumerCurve[i] = new Point (x,y);
    }

    //3*)instantiate points store in correct slots

}
```

I have the second part but I don't really know how to check for the invaid paramaters and getting the points in the right slot. Also, would it be the same for an array list? It might be cause I've looked at this code way too long and just missed it.

Comment: You are already checking for `np < 0`, just check for the other arguments in the same way. What should happen if the argument is invalid? `np = (Integer) null;` won't work - you can't assing `null` to a primitive type `int`. You should probably throw `IllegalArgumentException` in that case. What do you mean by storing the points in the correct slots? You have already created the array `myCurve` and all its elements, maybe you want to have it as instance field instead of a local variable?

Comment: There is nothing in the slots at the moment, because in another class the points are being created and then stored into the slots to create the curve. Essentially, I need to have it say that points are being stored in order (so (0,0) (1,1) etc.) in the slots

Comment: What exactly are the slots and where are they declared? You have already created the points in this method and they are currently ordered by `x`. Do you just want to store them elsewhere?

Comment: Let me edit my question with updated code that should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comments on the code:

```
Point[] myCurve = new Point [np]; // if np is negative here, you will get an exception
if( np< 0) {
    np= -1;
}
```

Here you have to check `np` *before* you use it in `new Point[np]`, otherwise you will get an exception in case of negative `np`. Setting `np` to `-1` doesn't solve the problem. You should either set it to `0`, or preferably throw an exception indicating that the argument is not acceptable:

```
if (np < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("'np' must not be negative");
}
```

Similarly for the other arguments if necessary.

If `Point` is `java.awt.Point`, then its constructor is `Point(int, int)` - you would have to cast the `double` to an `int`: `new Point(x, (int) y)`. If `Point` is your own class which accepts `double` in the constructor, then it's fine.

And finally, instead of storing the points to a local variable `myCurve`, why don't you store them directly in `myConsumerCurve` as you do in the `curve()` method?

```
myConsumerCurve = new Point [np];

for(int i=0; i<np; i++) {
    int x = i*dx;
    double y = m*x+b;
    myConsumerCurve[i] = new Point (x, y); // or 'new Point (x, (int) y)' if it's java.awt.Point
}
```

On a side note, it's a convention that methods start with lower case (i.e. `curve()`, not `Curve()`).

Comment: I just edited my code, I can't have the constructor be a void, so that will changes things, not sure what it should be though. Plus I need to create a for loop that searches through the array to see what the points are and then if one is negative say you can't have a negative

Comment: Constructors have no return type, and they must have the same name as the class. If you want `consumerCurve()` to be a constructor, you declare it as `public ConsumerCurve( ... )`.

Comment: I just realized that after I said it. How do I create a for loop that goes through the array and and looks for a negative number and if it finds one then says you can't have a negative

Comment: @retrogirl19 Just check the other arguments the same way you are checking `np`. If none of them are negative, then neither can `x` `y` be. Also move `Point[] myConsumerCurve = new Point [np];` after the argument checking, as mentioned in the answer.